# Exclude link text from the character count for moderator flags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, moderation, character-limit

A few hours ago I tried to flag a post/user as being from a duplicate account. This user has multiple accounts and keeps asking the same question (more or less) over and over again. So I tried to flag and started finding the old threads that it duplicates and the duplicate accounts.

But the 500 (?) characters limit was used up quite quickly when I posted the links.

Can links be treated differently in the character count, so that you can type five links each (about) 100 characters and still be able to write a message?

The specific case I flagged is done, I think.
The thread is deleted and my flag is "helpful" even though I couldn't post any links.

(Thanks to whoever took care of it.)

Comment: There are other ways to drastically shorten a link. E.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356654 is only 40 characters. But putting a bunch of links into a flag is rarely ever appropriate. Your flag was much better without the links - moderators could *easily* find those if they wanted.

Comment: @animuson "Be specific and detailed!" is the text to the flag. I thought that meant post links to show what you mean.

Comment: Specific and detailed does not mean repetitive. As I said, moderators can easily get to a list of their questions to look through them. More useful detail is describing the problem with that list of questions, not recreating the list of questions.

Comment: The information provided in the flag you raised was more than enough for me to deduce the problem and take the appropriate action. So...keep on doing what you're doing. It works for me. Like animuson said, we can find a list of questions pretty easily. Telling us your *observations* is the more important part, at least until they get the super seekrit mind-reading tools perfected. If you *desperately* need to include a bunch of links, shortening them to `q/356654` is fine, but linking to the user account(s) works even better.

Comment: few times I had problem referring multiple posts or accounts in flag message I've been using id's, like "post id #123456789" and "account id #123456789". This is less convenient than link but still sufficient to identify flagged post or user - and much shorter

Comment: @gnat yes. But I don't see the reason to go to all that trouble really. In the case as links are not needed as stated before why hold back on information so that the moderator have to dig up the same thing you did, and as you suggest shorten it to only id, that is trouble for both me and the moderator. I think the easiest is to just be able to post the links. If the moderator don't what or need the links they can just not click on them. I can be sure MY point is there (if moderator wants it) and moderator can just skip it if they don't like/need it.

Comment: I understand what you mean and what you suggest looks an improvement but it seems too minor to bother. As an example, I bump into such a limitation once in few thousands flags, it is really rare

Comment: @gnat it may be rare but it is probably an easy regex to it. Any word starting with "http" or "www" is excluded from character count.

Comment: if you have to add more and moar and moar links, better create a gist of all links and add the link to gist. But it is a double-work for the mods.

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider in these cases is to link a *search* that reveals the pattern you're describing. This effectively allows you to point out multiple questions and users at once. After all, how did you find all these questions without a search of some kind in the first place? (You still wish to link one or two questions/users explicitly.)